# How to add flag in a web based exam?

Tags: javascript

I want to add a simple flag that changes its color when clicked (*e.i. transparent flag changes to red when flagged*) for the web based exam I'm working on. Could someone help or give me a script on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use two images.  When it's clicked, you hide one image and show the other.  Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yzYJ3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344287800_YL8Ha-Ti.jpg">
<img src="http://photos.smugmug.com/photos/344284440_68L2K-Ti.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {position: relative; height: 66px; width: 100px;}
#container img {position: absolute; top:0; left:0}
```

JS (jQuery):

```
var flagged = false;
$("#container").click(function() {
    $(this).find("img").toggle();
    flagged = !flagged;
});
```

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the answer but could you help me out on the script on this?

Comment: oh sorry, i'm new on this site... i thought you were "Brian"... jfriend00, could you lend me a hand on this?

Comment: @Wycks - I added a code example to my answer with a working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/yzYJ3/

Comment: jfriend00, the HTML script doesn't seems to work. Kindly revised it please. -Thanks

Comment: @Wycks - What do you mean?  If you go to the jsfiddle link I posted in my answer and click on the image, you will see it swap each time you click.  What are you seeing differently?

Comment: i saw the link and it works just fine... the problems is, when I paste it on my work it doesn't change the picture. =(

Comment: You can't put readable code into a comment.  Did you get all three parts (HTML, CSS and jQuery)?

Comment: only the html and jquery... can i email you for the whole details? what's your email?

Answer (score 1):

Have a picture of a transparent flag and a flagged flag side-by-side in one picture (for example, the transparent one at {0, 0} and the red one at {0, 22} assuming a size of 22x22 pixels) and switch between them with JavaScript and CSS:

(In the CSS file)

```
.flag {
    background-image: url('flag.png');
    display: inline-block;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
}

.flag.active {
    background-position: 0 22px;
}
```

(In the JavaScript file)

```
function toggleFlag(flag) {
    if(/\bactive\b/.test(flag.className)) {
        flag.className = flag.className.replace(/(^|\s)active(\s|$)/g, "");
    } else {
        flag.className = flag.className ? flag.className + ' active' : 'active';
    }
}
```

Just call `toggleFlag` with the flag when it should be toggled.

Comment: minitech, where should i insert the flags in the javascript? (e.i. flag1 and flag2)... i'm sorry i'm kinda new in programming field.

Comment: You shouldn't use \b (word break) in the regular expression as it will match a '-' character which is allowed in a class name. Much better to use (^|\s} for the start and (\s|$) for the end. Or write a small *hasClass* function.

Comment: @Wycks: Attach it as an event handler. If you don't know how, look it up on Google ("javascript event listeners").

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jQuery and the examples at jQueryUI - http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: I'm not sure the OP needs a 4,000 line script library to support a jQuery solution when all that is required is 4 lines of code.